# MySQL Count(Table1.ColId) Where IN (any of Table2.Col1 ,Table2.Col2)

Tags: mysql, count

I have 2 Tables

```
Table 1 has Id, Name
Table 2 has Id, Col1_IdVal, Col2_IdVal,Col3_IdVal,Col4_IdVal
```

I would like simple solution for

```
Count(T1.Id) WHERE T1.Id In (T2.Col1_IdVal,T2.Col2_IdVal,T2.Col3_IdVal,T2.Col4_IdVal)
```

Something I have tried does not return correct result set , too few in the result :

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.Id) FROM Table1 As T1     
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2_1 ON T2_1.T2Column_1 = T1.Id     
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2_2 ON T2_2.T2Column_2 = T1.Id    
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2_3 ON T2_3.T2Column_3 = T1.Id    
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2_4 ON T2_4.T2Column_4 = T1.Id    
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2_5 ON T2_5.T2Column_5 = T1.Id;
```

Table 1 has Unique Values - it is Primary Key, Table 2 can have any number of values MANY.  Table2 columns are not foreign keys of Table1 - they are values that must exist in Table1 but other than that - they are not FKeys.

So basically Count(Id) Where Id Value Is in T2, Cols 1..n

Comment: What column is `IN (...)` ?  Perhaps you mean `T1.id IN (...)`?

Comment: @RickJames Yes - I missed that ..

Comment: Make the col names consistent.  Shorten the question to only 3 tables total.  Shorten the column names.  You say "not correct" -- too high?  Too low?  Are the tables 1:many?  (or what)?  Switch from `LEFT JOIN` to `EXISTS`?

Comment: You probably wanted inner joins, not outer.

Comment: @mustaccio No I do not want inner joins . With that it combines the joins and the resulting count is 0, I want to get a count for Id where it exists in the other T2.Columns 1 through x ..

Comment: @RickJames too low. Exists ?? In Subquery ??

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: LEFT JOIN will NOT eject non-matched pairs!!! It can only increase the count when duplicates by joining condition exists in slave table.

Answer (score 0):

Look for

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.Id) FROM Table1 As t1     
{ INNER | LEFT } JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Id IN (t2.T2Column_1,
                                                t2.T2Column_2,
                                                t2.T2Column_3,
                                                t2.T2Column_4,
                                                t2.T2Column_5);
```

Comment: I will test this tomorrow when I am back at work.